# how to rotate an imageview using opengl in android using continuous dynamic rotation angle values

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to rotate an android imageview continuously with dynamic rotation angle values. I tried with the normal angle rotation for imageview and also different animations(objectanimator along with easing types), but still there is a jerking(not smooth) in the needle(imageview) movement of the speedometer gauge. This rotation angles are generated continuously and randomly.How to rotate an imageview **using opengl** in android for smooth movement?

Comment: There is a jerking(not smooth) in the needle(imageview) movement of the speedometer gauge. This rotation angles are generated continuously and randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. The cause is, if you rotate any view, it will trigger it's parent views to rescale and it's sibling views too, that is a very expensive task and it causes the lag. But you don't need to go to opengl level for this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class RotatableImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private float angle = 0f;

    public RotatableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RotatableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RotatableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void rotate(float angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int save = canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(angle, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(save);
    }
}
```

You just need to rotate the canvas before the Imageview draws the image. Use the above RotatableImageView.java class.

Then just call `imageView.rotate(yourAngle)` will do the trick.

Code posted [here](https://gist.github.com/sujithkanna/9da2235e90dd77e2a5ca16006a3bf98e)

Comment: Still i am facing the jerking issue after implementing the above fix provided @ Sujith Niraikulathan. Here is my code `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.n_sport_needle), null, new RectF(0, 0, 300, 300), null);
rpm_shadow.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
for (j1 = 0; j1 < 250; j1++) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
rpm_shadow.rotate((float) j1);
    }
});
} `

Comment: Why are you creating a bitmap here?? Why is been written on another bitmap??

Comment: I was trying to place an image(needle, 300dpX300dp) in canvas, for making it rotate. I want to make the needle(image) movement as smooth as we seen in our automobiles rpm or in speedometer without any jerking. Thanks @ Sujith Niraikulathan for the response...

Comment: That's ok, now why are you using for loop here?? It will immediately rotate the image to 250, the rotation animation you won't notice, try to use value animator for testing

Comment: i have used both object and value animators and checked, still there is jerking...i used, for loop(linear increment along with a 25 mili thread sleep) here for just making the question understandable that these dynamic values can be linear or non linear....